# jQuery select list item to display none based on data-attribute

Tags: jquery

I have the following dynamically created list......

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
  <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Select a country…</li>
  <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Austria</li>
  <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Denmark</li>
  <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Finland</li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking to remove the list item by selecting the data-option-array-index if it equals a certain number, say 3. I have tried the following with no success......

```
$( ".chosen-results").find("[data-option-array-index=3]").css("display", "none");
```

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are dealing with the chosen plugin... then you will have to update its source... else it seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BXFfT/1/

Comment: Your code is working, http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3Nu/,  check if you have added jQuery and put the code in document.ready

Comment: I've loaded jQuery and $(document).ready(); correctly as $( ".chosen-results").css("display", "none"); will hide the whole list for me but I can't seem to select the desired item by data-option-array-index! Confused!Maybe I will have to edit the source code of the plugin, although I wanted to avoid this for future updates!

Comment: Ok thanks guys, problem solved, the list wasn't being generated on body load, it was only loaded when a select input type was clicked, therefore the code had already ran before the list was generated. Thanks for the help!